# Is it a way to get Knockout keep doing binding even it failed for the previous one

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0, knockout-mvc

Is it a way to let KO keep doing the binding for the rest of the elements,

```html
<div id='div1' data-bind="wrong:aaaaa"></div>
<div id='div2' data-bind="value:qty"></div>
```

as "wrong" in "div1" is not a proper binding, knockout will stops there and will not try to bind "div2"
is it a way to get KO keep doing the binding for "div2" thought that it has error on "div1"

thanks

Comment: I don't see the point, just remove that binding if it is wrong, you can use different attribute for some magic stuff you want to do with div1.

Comment: basically we do have a custombinding "wrong" which is working sometimes,  the error message is "Object doesn't support property or method  'wrong'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out it is not causing by KO, it is the code inside the custombinding stops it from working